# iOS unable to archive [RN 0.63.3] AccessibilityResources.bundle not found

Tags: ios, swift, react-native, react-native-ios

I'm facing the [same issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/29709) since some days. The workarounds didn't work for me.

I am unable to archive the project for release:

```
error: Resource "/Users/cedricjung/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/decouverto-asvavlxsbksyvhgovxmjpnlracmz/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/decouverto/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/React-Core/AccessibilityResources.bundle" not found. Run 'pod install' to update the copy resources script.
```

You can check all source code [there](https://github.com/decouverto/les-balades-de-decouverto-ios).
I'm using `react-native` v0.63.3.

I'm new in iOS development even if I use `react-native` since 3 years.

Thank you for your help. :)

Comment: Have you tried `pod install`? (You probably have but just making sure)

Comment: Yes I had. And unfortunately it doesn't solved the problem.